# R dcast: How do I perform dcast value calculations?

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

I have a large data frame, with which I run this:

```
dcast(mydata, People ~ Categories, value.var = "Answer Count", **sum**)
```

and this is the result:

```
People  category1   category2
Marge   3,648   6,402
Homer   3,586   6,684
Bart    3,469   7,119
Lisa    4,045   6,758
Maggie  2,847   5,748
```

Also, this:

```
dcast(mydata, People ~ Categories, value.var = "Answer Count", **length**)
```

Makes this:

```
People  category1   category2
Marge   2,531   4,516
Homer   2,535   4,512
Bart    2,542   4,563
Lisa    2,501   4,488
Maggie  2,517   4,513
```

Effectively, I want to do this:

```
dcast(mydata, People ~ Categories, value.var = "Answer Count", **sum / length / 6**)
```

and get these values:

```
People  category1   category2
Marge   0.240221256 0.236271036
Homer   0.235765943 0.246897163
Bart    0.227445581 0.260026298
Lisa    0.269558843 0.250965538
Maggie  0.188518077 0.212275648
```

I've tried manipulating `fun.aggregate` as an argument but I'm not sure that's the correct path, or I don't know what I'm doing.  Could someone help me with this please?  (Sidenote: this sample has two categories.  The real data has >40.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an anonymous function call in `fun.aggregate`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydata, People ~ Categories, 
   value.var = "Answer Count", fun.aggregate = function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
```

Comment: I was so close.  Thank you so much akrun! :)